# How to target a part of CSS class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Example 1 works:

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="prefix-item-suffix">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div[class^="prefix"][class$="suffix"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Example 2 doesn't:

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="multiple prefix-item-suffix classes">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div[class^="prefix"][class$="suffix"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Example 2 has multiple classes so CSS approach stops working. In real time project the multiple classes will be random except the one targeted in between them, the value between `prefix-the_dynamic_value-suffix` will also be random, how to target that with other classes inside same element? Because example 1 approach doesn't work.

Comment: if item is on all then can add `item red`.. then class selector would be `.item.red`, without a space between.. then it has to have at least `class="item red"`.. is just basic css

Comment: `[attribute^='value']` and `[attribute$='value']` just selects HTML tags that begin with the attribute value and ends with the attribute value, respectively. That does not mean that it will see if a `class` attribute value within your attribute begins with or ends with the value. Just use `div.prefix-item-suffix{}` and create other classes to do other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `[class*=…]`

```css
div[class*="prefix-"][class*="-suffix"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="multiple prefix-item-suffix classes">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `*=` just means contains, and does not account for order.

Comment: You'll need to add the appropriate hyphen after the prefix match and before the suffix match. Otherwise, you'll match all classes having the string in any part of the class. For example, `[class*="prefix-"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with js by checking if some class on the element starts with `prefix` and ends with `suffix`. If the check returns true then you run your code.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.items > div').forEach(el => {
  const check = [...el.classList].some(cls => {
    return cls.startsWith('prefix') && cls.endsWith('suffix')
  })

  if (check) {
    el.style.color = 'red'
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="multiple prefix-item-suffix classes">item 2</div>
  <div class="item prefix-item-suffix-not-this">item 3</div>
</div>
```